# C++ check if a date is valid

Tags: c++, date, time

is there any function to check if a given date is valid or not?
I don't want to write anything from scratch.

e.g. 32/10/2012 is not valid
and 10/10/2010 is valid

Comment: Where does this value originate?  What is done with it?

Comment: it's the input. I just wanna check if it's valid or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your string is always in that format the easiest thing to do would be to split the string into its three components, populate a `tm` structure and pass it to `mktime()`. If it returns -1 then it's not a valid date.

You could also use [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#io_objects.format_date_parser) to parse it:

```
string inp("10/10/2010");
string format("%d/%m/%Y");
date d;
d = parser.parse_date(inp, format, svp);
```

Comment: What svp and parser are?

Comment: mktime will normalize a date. For example, if the day is negative, it will wrap back to the previous month and adjust the day and month members accordingly.

Comment: [mktime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime): _The values in time are permitted to be outside their normal ranges_

Comment: please add full header and typedef to your code.

Answer (score 4):

The boost date time class should be able to handle what you require.
See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: Or the current version, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: Ahh. Yes, let me edit my post to reflect that. Thank you Fred.

Comment: Or what I'm sure is the current release link. :) Thank you Vlad.

Answer (score 3):

If the format of the date is constant and you don't want to use boost, you can always use `strptime`, defined in the `ctime` header:

```
const char date1[] = "32/10/2012";
const char date2[] = "10/10/2012";
struct tm tm;

if (!strptime(date1, "%d/%m/%Y", &tm)) std::cout << "date1 isn't valid\n";
if (!strptime(date2, "%d/%m/%Y", &tm)) std::cout << "date2 isn't valid\n";
```

Comment: Bear in mind `strptime()` is a non-standard extension that is not available on all systems (including Windows).

Comment: @spencercw: Indeed. There are, however, open source implementations for most systems, including Windows. Also, it's a POSIX's standard. :)

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem recently, but unfortunately didn't figure out `boost`, and `mktime` didn't solve my problem. So I decided to manually throw a check for date-time. Hope, it will help someone

```
 bool isDateAndtimeValid( std::vector<int> time ) {
    if( time[1]> 12) return false; //month
    if( time[2]> 31 ) return false; //day
    if( time[2] == 31 and ( time[1] == 4 or time[1] == 6 or time[1] == 9 or time[1] == 11 ) ) return false; //30 days in Apr, Jun, Sen, Nov
    if( time[1] == 2) {
      if( time[2] > 29 ) return false;
      if( time[2] == 29 and ( ( time[0]%100 )%4 != 0) ) return false;
    } //Feb
    if( time[3] > 23) return false; //hours
    if( time[4] > 59 ) return false; //min
    if( time[5] > 59) return false; //sec
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When this question was asked and answered, there was no [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).  But if you're running into the same problem today, that's what you would want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just like this, (in this example I used `-` as date separator you can replace `-` with `\` and test it).

I just split the given date into three parts `Y-D-M` then store them into `tm` struct, in order to convert it to [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Here is the `tm` struct content:

```
struct tm {
   int tm_sec;         /* seconds,  range 0 to 59          */
   int tm_min;         /* minutes, range 0 to 59           */
   int tm_hour;        /* hours, range 0 to 23             */
   int tm_mday;        /* day of the month, range 1 to 31  */
   int tm_mon;         /* month, range 0 to 11             */
   int tm_year;        /* The number of years since 1900   */
   int tm_wday;        /* day of the week, range 0 to 6    */
   int tm_yday;        /* day in the year, range 0 to 365  */
   int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time             */   
};
```

for example you entered this date `2024-02-31` and then stored it into `tm` struct, when you will call `mktime()` it will fix the bad range you entered, since there is no `31`st day in `February`, then you can compare the old `tm` and the new `tm` and check if their values match, if not then the date is not valid.

```cpp
bool checkDateFormat(const std::string& dateString) {

    char dash;
    std::stringstream ss(dateString);

    struct tm date;
    struct tm newDate;

    ss >> date.tm_year >> dash >> date.tm_mon >> dash >> date.tm_mday;
    date.tm_year -= 1900; date.tm_mon -= 1;
    date.tm_hour = 1;            // Hour
    date.tm_min = 0;             // Minute
    date.tm_sec = 0;             // Second    

    newDate = date;
    time_t unix_time = mktime(&newDate);
    if (
        date.tm_year == newDate.tm_year &&
        date.tm_mon == newDate.tm_mon   &&
        date.tm_mday == newDate.tm_mday
    )   
        return true; 
    return false;
}

int main() {

    if (checkDateFormat("2024-02-31") == true)
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
}
```

you can also print their dates in a readable format like the following:

```cpp
char buffer[1337];
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", &date );
std::cout << "date entered: " + std::string(buffer) << std::endl;
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%c", &newDate );
std::cout << "date after rounding with mktime: " + std::string(buffer) << std::endl;
```

insert this code part just after this line

```
time_t unix_time = mktime(&newDate);
```

here is an example of what will you get:

```
date entered: Sun Feb 31 01:00:00 2024
date after rounding with mktime: Sat Mar  2 02:00:00 2024
```

as you can see `31 Feb` became `2 Mar`, since `2024/Feb` has just `29 days` it got rounded.

Comment: thanks for @spencercw for his answer, I got to come with this answer

Answer (score 0):

C++20 now makes this easier:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

bool
is_valid_date(std::string date)
{
    std::istringstream in{std::move(date)};
    std::chrono::year_month_day ymd;
    in >> std::chrono::parse("%d/%m/%Y", ymd);
    return !in.fail();
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << is_valid_date("32/10/2012") << '\n';
    std::cout << is_valid_date("10/10/2010") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oZQwN9PXixdWgtzW)

MSVC has this.  Coming soon with gcc-14.  LLVM is in the implementation stage (as I write this).