# Check date with C++

Tags: c++, date

I would like to check IF the current date is a specific set date, and if that date is correct, I would like it to run a code block. Else it will end the script.
What I'm thinking, is it will look like this:

```
int/string? date = ????;

if(date==10/07/13){
    }
else 
    return 0;
```

I would have a variable named date, which would get the current date. 
The issues i see is having the slashes within it. Also, i would like to add that i am writing this on an english Windows 7 computer, and i would like it to be opened on a dutch windows 7 computer.. Will that be an issue?

Comment: You should be able to use the `std::time` function from `<ctime>`, modulo details about timezones. E.g. use `std::localtime` to parse the current timestamp into a `tm` structure and compare year, month and day.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan, I will have to do some research on this function and see what I can do. Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436697/c-check-if-a-date-is-valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t tp = std::time(NULL);   // current time, an integer
                                        // counting seconds since epoch

    std::tm * ts = std::localtime(&tp); // parsed into human conventions


    std::cout << "Year: " << 1900 + ts->tm_year << "\n"
              << "Month: " << ts->tm_mon << "\n"
              << "Day: " << ts->tm_mday << "\n"
        ;
}
```

Instead of `localtime` (which uses the current locale) you can also use `gmtime` to get the time in UTC.

Comment: 'unable to resolve identifier nullptr'  I have included the <ctime> and <iostream>

Comment: @Darryl: Use `NULL` instead. I wrote modern C++; if you have an older platform, you'll need to adapt it to C++98.

Comment: 'ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'tp' with no type. I have also change that to NULL.

Comment: @Darryl: As I said, you have to port this to C++98 if you don't have a modern platform. The first type is `std::time_t`, the second is `std::tm *`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

string dateString(tm *locTime)
{
return to_string(locTime->tm_year) + "/" + to_string(locTime->tm_mon) + "/" + to_string(locTime->tm_mday)
}

int main( )
{
   time_t now = time(0);
   tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
   if(dateString(ltm)=="YYYY/MM/DD")
   {statements}
}
```

`tm` structure contains integers like tm_year,tm_mon,tm_mday. You can compare them to integers or build a simple comparable string date format from them.